# Insert Contents of 1 Zip into another Zip with java

Tags: java, zip, truezip

Okay, So I need a way to take `A.zip` and insert its contents into `b.zip` In java. Also I need it to overwrite any files in `b.zip` that exist in `a.zip`.
Now, I've been trying for hours to do this with [TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net). And I've tried a billion different ways only to all end In some sort of logic error. It just doesn't seem possible. But yet I know 7-zip can do it. Any help or hints would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be as easy as `new TFile("a.zip").cp_rp(new TFile("b.zip"));`

Comment: can you do that step-by-step like: unzip 1)A.zip 2)unzip b.zip 3)copy filse from a.zip folder to b.zip folder. 4)zip b.folder?

Comment: @noone I'll try that, But I think I tried it last night and It completly overwrote the b.zip.

Comment: Ensure that your class path contains the TrueZIP Driver ZIP module. Then the one line statement in the first comment should work unless a.zip or b.zip use unsupported features like the Extended Deflater algorithm or so.